# VSCode Ruins MousePad Scrolling Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, scrolling, visual-studio-code

I've recently started coding in VSCode as it's a good IDE for flutter. In doing so I started realizing that randomly in coding sessions my mousepad's scrolling feature stops working (not only in VSCode but in the entire system). I thought maybe it's somehow caused by VSCode and when I saw this thread: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/13612 and others about the issue I'm now sure that it's caused by VSCode.

Thing is, in the above thread they say that bug was fixed in an October 2018 update to Windows 10. I'm fully updated, even tried that fix anyhow and nothing seems to solve the issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)